# SQL Server Compact Insertion

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

i want to insert data into sql server Compact edition the database table screenshot is [Here >>>](http://www.flickr.com/photos/56760865@N04/7657986538) 
i Want to add data in users the addition script is as follows

```
SqlCeConnection Con = new SqlCeConnection();
Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = 'Database.sdf';" +
                       "Password='Password';";
Con.Open();
int Amount=Convert.ToInt32(AmBox.Text),
Code=Convert.ToInt32(MCode.Text),
Num=Convert.ToInt32(MNum.Text);
string Name=Convert.ToString(NBox.Text),
FName=Convert.ToString(SOBox.Text),
Address=Convert.ToString(AdBox.Text);

SqlCeCommand Query =new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Users VALUES " + 
                        "(++ID,Name,FName,Address,Code,Num,Amount)",Con);
Query.ExecuteReader();
```

When it runs it generates an error SAYING "The column name is not valid [Node Name (if any) =,Column name=ID ]

I don't figure out the problem kindly tell me thanks!

Comment: Better learn how strings work. you're not inserting your variables into that query - you're inserting plain text that happens to LOOK like your variables' names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change your code to something like this

```
using(SqlCeConnection Con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = 'Database.sdf';" + 
                                                "Password='Password';")
{ 
    Con.Open(); 
    SqlCeCommand Query = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Users " + 
                             "(Name,FName,Address,MCode,MNum,Amount) " +
                             "VALUES (@Name,@FName,@Address,@Code,@Num,@Amount)",Con); 

    Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NBox.Text);
    Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", SOBox.Text)); 
    Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address",AdBox.Text)); 
    Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", Convert.ToInt32(MCode.Text));
    Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num", Convert.ToInt32(MNum.Text));
    Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount" , Convert.ToInt32(AmBox.Text));
    Query.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

- The using statement guarantees the correct disposing of  the
  connection
- The Parameter collection avoid Sql Injection Attacks and quoting
  problems
- Use of `ExecuteNonQuery` because this is an insert query.
- Removed the ++ID, it is not a valid value to pass to the database

If the ID field is an Identity column, then you don't pass any value from code, but let the database calculate the next value.
Also, I'm not sure you really need the single quote in your connection string around the data source and password keys.

EDIT ---
Sometimes the .SDF database could be located in a different folder. 
(Modern operating systems prevent writing in the application folder).
In this case is necessary to set the path to the SDF file in the connection string.
For example, the SDF could be located in a subfolder of the C:\ProgramData directory.

```
string conString = "Data Source=" + 
        Path.Combine(
               Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),
               "MyAppData\\database.sdf") + ";Password=yourPassword;";
```

Comment: Run time Exception Is Occurring saying "The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = Code ]" at  Query.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Right, just renamed Code in MCode and Num in MNum as from your schema

Comment: Al Right Thanks Steve But Problem is still there query runs without an error but when i check database there is no data in it what's happening...??

Comment: Sometime happens to look at the wrong database. In the connection string there is no path, so the database updated should be in the BIN\DEBUG or BIN\RELEASE directory of your solution.

Comment: So Steve How to avoid this so that database who updated will be in default folder showing on the top right in VC#

Comment: Answer updated with some information on how to set a specific directory in the connectionstring

Comment: But When I Put My Application in installer format than the user who is using this app may can't find SDF File In AppData Folder How To Avoid This Also Explain This Code >>> Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData

Comment: This is the reference on [GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx), for the installation problem, it depends on your installer tool. You should be able to specify where you want to install a particular file and adjust the connection string accordingly.

Comment: And this is the reference to [SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration

Comment: OK Steve I Will Do This If Problem Arises I Will Again Comment Here Anyway Thanks A Lot For Your Help

Comment: Sorry, made an error in Path.Combine, look at the corrected string now

Comment: But Path is still there the compiler generates an error saying that path is undeclared

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14584/discussion-between-user1366440-and-steve)

Comment: Need `using System.IO;` to use the namespace where Path class is declared inside the framework.

Comment: when i use your code it looks for DB file in C:\AppData but my file is in C:documents visual studio projects

Comment: let's do one thing Steve can you send me your email i will PM you the exact code so that you will see

Comment: Steve kindly send me your SKYPE ID i want to talk to you to solve this matter Please